# Sunday resets my consecutive days :(

Tags: support, consecutive-days

Ok so I'm new on the SO network and I'm trying to be helpful answering questions when I can. I've logged in faithfully every day for over 2 weeks now, but every time 12 o'clock sunday morning rolls around it seems I lose my consecutive day count.

What gives? I wanna earn my fanatic badge :) I feel I'm already pretty fanatical about this site, see how worked up I get about a badge :D

Comment: Fanatic?  One step at a time... Enthusiast first.  :)

Comment: If you click the consecutive days line in [your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/572588/userzer0) you can see which days are missing. Are you factoring in your time zone? The Stack Overflow day ends at midnight UTC, not midnight local time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our day is in UTC.

Therefore, to be "seen" on a site for a given day, you must perform some non-trivial action on a site between 00:00:00 UTC and 23:59:59 UTC on that day.

Comment: Is voting a "trivial action"?

Comment: Ok, so non-trival actions. Now that makes sense, if only the badge said visit AND perform a non-trivial action every day for xx days. :) Thanks.

Comment: Where can I find about what's considered a non trivial action?

Comment: Looks like Firefox addon request is considered "non-trivial" action: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142830/am-i-too-fanatic