# Fanatic badge days count reset to zero , account's "visited x days" shows 59 Days

Tags: support, consecutive-days, activity-badges, visited-days

Had 52 consecutive days count/Fanatic badge suddenly down to zero.
I logged in continuously and I stayed aware of the UTC timing and didn't just go to the home page.

This is the second occurrence of such behavior. It was reported by other users as well.

Below screenshots show visit action consecutively for 59 days (7 Jul - 4 Sep) with action range of(login/answer/vote/question). Now the count shown 4 but account's "visited x days" shows 59.

This might be a miscalculation of some sort. Action needed to reg a login is visiting "Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)"
[image]

Comment: Why did you delete your earlier [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315007/fanatic-badge-total-consecutive-login-days-count-reset-to-zero) and then repost the exact same content again?

Comment: Looks like you missed 31 Aug

Comment: that is my point Rory , why it wasn't reg there , although that day had same actions set as the prior ones

Comment: [Fanatic badges are still being awarded](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83?page=1) so if it is a bug it is limited to specific user accounts, probably only yours.

Comment: This isn't the second occurrence... the previous report was also by you. If it has been reported by someone _else_, please link that post so that we can see the discussion and verdict there.

Comment: Again, your [all activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5723127/wesam?tab=activity) doesn't show anything publicly visible actions, though we don't know if you did anything else, like voting or flagging. AFAIK, there's a certain minimum action that will count as "visited".

Comment: by second occurrence i meant the secound time it happen to me , you can pick that up from the context ,anyway here you go https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78211/sunday-resets-my-consecutive-days

Comment: Otherwise, you might had a misunderstanding (or bad luck) just like https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66482/241919 . I should have said before on the previous deleted question to list all SO pages visited on that day from your browser's history...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it [was already posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315007/fanatic-badge-total-consecutive-login-days-count-reset-to-zero) and OP waste our time by deleting and re-asking from scratch.

Comment: There are [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/is-there-a-minimum-level-of-activity-required-to-get-the-enthusiast-badge) [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1675/how-do-you-earn-the-enthusiast-badge?noredirect=1&lq=1) about what counts as activity (it's not just visiting / loading the site).

Answer (score 5):

"Visited x days" just means you have visited the site at *x* different days in the past, **not necessarily consecutive**. This is independent from the Fanatic badge progress, for that you have to look at the "*y* consecutive" part of the label.

The activity calendar shows some gaps (the days which aren't marked green), including one on August 31st, which is consistent with resetting the Fanatic badge count.

Comment: The last gap is on August 31st.

Comment: Unless you know exactly what you did on August 31st (maybe your browser history can tell you?), the only way to confirm it's a [bug] is having it investigated by SE staff.

Comment: @Wesam if it's "only a badge," why did you ask about this twice?

Comment: raising a flag about an issue to help the community